# C# with WPF Call UserControl form from Window Form

Tags: c#

Actually, I'm using C# with WPF. Let me explain again:

1. I have create UserControl (WPF) with one Button (Click on Button to create Image and textBox (Like New Folder)).
2. And I have another Window form (WPF) with Button and I want to Click on Button in Window Form to do Action instead of Button in UserControl. Here is the code of UserControl:

```cpp
private void btnNewRoom_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        Image img = new Image();
        img.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
        img.Width = 100;
        img.Height = 100;


        var assemblyLocation = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        var applicationDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyLocation);
        img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Resources/Images/folder.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

        StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Width = 120;
        tb.Height = 25;
        tb.Text = "New Folder";            

        sp.Children.Add(img);
        sp.Children.Add(tb);


        AddNewRoom.Children.Add(sp);
    }
```

and It is possible ?

Note: Any good way to Click button to Create Image and TextBox?

Comment: You cloud have edited and clearified [your first question on this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10528906/205233) instead of posting a new question. It's not really nice to leave people trying to help you solving your problem with a stale question. Also add the `WCF` tag to categorize your question.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a static event handler in your WPF control, and simply call it from your Window Form's button click event.